# Can't split CasperJS tests across multiple files

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

The docs weren't really useful - too brief and vague. As I understood from the [docs](http://casperjs.org/testing.html), We just need to to run casperjs command on the the directory of tests and ensure each test ends with `Tester.done()`. Here are my two tests,

```
//test1.js
var casper = require('casper').create();

var urlPrefix = "http://localhost/NavHawk2/";

casper.start(urlPrefix , function() {
    this.test.assertSelectorHasText('title', 'Login', 'Title Ok! Login Page Expected');
    this.test.assertExists('form[action$="/login"]', 'Login Form is found');
    this.fill('form[action$="/login"]', {
        .....
    }, true);
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.test.done(2);
});


//test2.js
var blinkingCircleImg = "7.gif"

casper.on('page.error', function(){
    console.log("SOme Javascript error persists!");
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.test.assertSelectorHasText('title', 'Map', 'Login Ok! Map Page Expected');
    this.test.assertExists('img[src$="' + blinkingCircleImg + '"]', 'Blinking Circle being shown!');
    this.test.assetNotVisible('#sidebar_content_geofences', 'Geofencing sidebar not being shown!');
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.test.renderResults(true);
    this.test.done(3);
});
```

The thing is that `test2.js` file is never run. Maybe I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: How is `test2.js` loaded in the first place?

Comment: @PaulGrime: How is it supposed to be loaded? Docs weren't clear.

Comment: Can you show your folder structure? I'm not sure where test2.js is loaded.

Comment: @PaulGrime: They are in the same folder.

Answer (score 16):

Several things here:

- you must use the `casperjs test` subcommand
- you may **not** create a new casper instance within a test script
- you may **not** call .renderResults when using the `casperjs test` subcommand
- tests scripts within a given directory will be executed in the alphabetical order of their filename

There's a [useful gist](https://gist.github.com/n1k0/3813361) which demonstrates how the command may/should be used.

Comment: Is there anyway I can split tests without alphabetical restriction? I mean what i need is login.js to execute first , then some other page.

Comment: name your files accordingly: 01_login.js, 02_otherpage.js