# Tests not executed with casperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I have two tests files in the same folder : `test_a.js` and `test_b.js`.
When I run `casperjs test folder`, only `test_a.js` is executed.

Both tests are built this way :

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.test.begin('Test description', n, function(test) {
    casper.start(SERVER).then(function() {
        // Some basic tests
    });

    casper.run(function(){
        test.done();
        this.exit();
    });
});
```

Would you guys know why ? (tests are very basic, so I don't include them for readability. If you wish to see them, please let me know :) )

Comment: Are you sure about `this.exit();` ?

Comment: Yep. If i don't have it, it runs the first tests and keep waiting something (I have to ctrl-C to stop it).

Comment: Have a look at https://gist.github.com/n1k0/3813361. It could be the bug of Casper.

Comment: Looks similar indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the solution on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371091/cant-split-casperjs-tests-across-multiple-files). I just had to take away the

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
```

and put the `this.exit()` in only one file.

Comment: You shouldn't have an `exit` anywhere. The `test` environment usually exits on its own. Also you can probably accept your answer.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I guess you're right, but I'm intrigued with your comment on `exit`. Could you pleaseelaborate on that ?

Comment: I don't know how it was with the previous versions of CasperJS, but in 1.1.0-beta3, you don't need to exit. CasperJS does it for you when all tests have completed.